# Sudo fails when running as service

Tags: linux, permissions, arch-linux, sudo, systemd

I have a program that runs as a normal user but sometimes needs to run a command that requires root privileges. So I made a shell script and gave the user permission to run that script with sudo.

The script is executed successfully when I run the program from the shell but fails when running as a service. Sudo exits with this error:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with
the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?0
```

[This](http://hastebin.com/pawenumude) is the unit file for the service, [this](http://hastebin.com/zikedaneka) is the script and in `sudoers` I have added

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

I have no idea why. Sudo works fine and the permissions for `/usr/bin` and `/usr/bin/sudo` are correct.

Comment: Please include the content of your files instead of using links. The files can be removed from the hosting server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set `NoNewPrivileges=true` in the unit file

From the documentation:

If true, ensures that the service process and all its children can never gain new privileges. This option is more powerful than the respective secure bits flags (see above), as it also prohibits UID changes of any kind. This is the simplest, most effective way to ensure that a process and its children can never elevate privileges again.

Therefore, sudo will not get root privileges even if the executable has the suid bit set

Comment: I did not write the unit file so I was not so sure about what the options mean. Thank you.